Archaeological cultures dataset (GeoJSON or other format)?
I am looking for "archaeological culture" map boundaries and points, like this list of Upper-Paleolithic cultures on Wikipedia. Quick sample:


The Aurignacian culture was located in Europe and south west Asia, and flourished between 43,000 and 26,000 BP. It may have been contemporary with the Périgordian (a contested grouping of the earlier Châtelperronian and later Gravettian cultures).
The Gravettian culture was located across Europe. Gravettian sites generally date between 33,000 and 20,000 BP.
The Solutrean culture was located in eastern France, Spain, and England. Solutrean artifacts have been dated c. 22,000 to 17,000 BP.
The Magdalenian culture left evidence from Portugal to Poland during the period from 17,000 to 12,000 BP.


Some sample maps of the Gravettian culture include:


Another culture map, the Aurignacian culture (Wikipedia):

Do we have any such robust (or not robust) datasets collecting dozens or hundreds of archaeological cultures into map boundaries or map points, perhaps in GeoJSON or some other format? Along with the culture name and rough timeframe?
I have asked a few GIS / map experts, and they say the only way to do it is to research each culture, and draw the map boundaries by hand. As there are at least 100-1000 I would like to do, from around the globe (not just Europe/Levant/Mediterranean), that would be very expensive and time consuming, so hoping to find another existing dataset or approach.
